# Parse data from a .csv into another file

Tags: python

I need to copy the contents of a .csv, that gets dumped from SQL each night to a folder location on my Ubuntu server that contains 100s of IP addresses to an area within a .conf file.
The csv puts all the IP addresses on the first row, separated with a space between each IP:

`192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3 192.168.0.4`

When I open the csv in Excel it looks like:

`['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2', '192.168.0.3', '192.168.0.4']`

And I need it to put into a file called something like routers.conf like this on row 2, but I need it be formatted like below and include the " instead of 'around the IP, add the :161 etc and inject into row 2 and replace what is there:

```
  [[inputs.snmp]]
    agents ["192.168.0.1:161","192.168.0.2:161","192.168.0.3:161","192.168.0.4:161"]
    version = 2
    community = "publicblah"
    interval = "120s"
    timeout = "5s"
    retries = 0
```

Could Python do this?

I'm currently using this to open and view it:

```
    with open("ip.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=" ")
        header = next(reader)
        print(header)
```

I did have a play with the outfile = open and outfile.write options, but get lost as this just writes a new .csv.

Any hope to parse this data, format it, and inject/replace the data in another file would be most welcome.

Comment: Suggest you look at the python library jinja2.  it will let you have template file with the data for the output already formed correctly and allow you to define substitution fields that will just take a python variable.  you feed the template file info and the items to replace to the jinja methods and it returns a string that can be written out as the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, let me know if you need any help!

```
import csv

# Step 1: Read the IP addresses from the CSV file
with open("ip.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=" ")
    ip_addresses = next(reader)

# Step 2: Format the IP addresses
formatted_ips = [f'"{ip}:161"' for ip in ip_addresses]

# Step 3: Join the IP addresses
ip_string = ', '.join(formatted_ips)
ip_string = f'agents = [{ip_string}]'

# Step 4: Read the routers.conf file
with open('routers.conf', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# Step 5: Replace the second line
lines[1] = ip_string + '\n'

# Step 6: Write the modified lines back into the file
with open('routers.conf', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about the single quotation mark as you see, because a string like `"abcdef"` or a character like `"a"` doesn't contain the **QUOTATION MARK**.
Python uses quotation marks to remind you that this is a string (or a character). Below is my code.

```
FILE_NAME = "ip.csv" #Your csv file
infile = open(FILE_NAME, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
IPs = infile.readlines()[0].split(" ") # Now Ips is a list:  ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2', '192.168.0.3', '192.168.0.4']
infile.close()
ips_str = '['
for ip in IPs:
    ips_str = ips_str +'"' +ip + ':161",'
ips_str = ips_str[0:-1:1] + "]" 
#Now ips_str is: '["192.168.0.1:161","192.168.0.2:161","192.168.0.3:161","192.168.0.4:161"]'
# But a string or character doesn't contain the QUATATION MARKS
output_text = '[[inputs.snmp]]\n\tagents ' + ips_str +'\n'+'\tversion = 2\n\tcommunity = "publicblah"\n\tinterval = "120s"\n\ttimeout = "5s"\n\tretries = 0'
OUTPUT_FILE = "config.conf" #REPLACE it with your config file name

with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w") as out:
    out.write(output_text)
```

More about string in Python, or in some other languages:

- You could use `len()` to get the length of a string.
  e.g.,

```py
string1 = 's'
print(string1)
```

You'll get 1 rather than 3, so obviously the quotation marks aren't included.